# Use for of loop to iterate the array

Tags: arrays, loops, class, for-loop

Assignment task4: Add the listStudents() method

In this task, you will add a method to the Bootcamp class that lists all the registered students' names and emails.
Create a method in the Bootcamp class named listStudents().
In the method body:
Check if the this.students array is empty.
If so, console.log() the message:
`No students are registered to the ${this.name} bootcamp.`
Then return the boolean value of false.
Otherwise, console.log() the line:
`The students registered in ${this.name} are:`
Then iterate through the entire this.students array and console.log() the name and email of each student on one line for each student. See the Testing section below for an example of the expected output.
You can do this with the for...of loop.
Finally, return the boolean value of true.
Testing code:

```
const runTest = (bootcamp, student) => {
const attemptOne = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
const attemptTwo = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
const attemptThree = bootcamp.registerStudent(new Student("Babs Bunny"));
if ( attemptOne && !attemptTwo && !attemptThree) {
    console.log("TASK 3: PASS");
}

bootcamp.registerStudent(new Student('Babs Bunny', 'babs@bunny.com'));
if (bootcamp.listStudents()) {
    console.log("TASK 4: PASS 1/2");
}
bootcamp.students = [];
if (!bootcamp.listStudents()) {
    console.log("TASK 4: PASS 2/2");
}
```

};

My code below does not work. Please help me review. Thanks

```
class Bootcamp {
constructor(name, level, students = []){
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.students = students;
}
registerStudent(studentToRegister){
    if (!studentToRegister.name || !studentToRegister.email) {
        console.log("Invalid name or email");
        return false;
    } else if(this.students.filter(s => s.email === studentToRegister.email).length) {
        console.log("This email is already registered");
        return false;
    } else {
        this.students.push(studentToRegister)
        console.log(`Successful registration ${studentToRegister.name} ${Bootcamp.name}`)
        return true;
    }
}
listStudent(registerStudent){
  if(this.students.length === 0)
  {
    console.log(`No students are registered to the ${this.name} bootcamp.`);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(`The students registered in ${this.name} are:`);
    for(const registerStudent of this.students)
    {
    console.log("Name:" + registerStudent[name] + "Email:" + registerStudent[email]);  
    return true;
    }
  }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
listStudents() {
        if (this.students.length == 0) {
          console.log("No students are registered to the ${this.name} bootcamp");
          return false;
        } else {
          console.log("The students registered in ${this.name} are:");
          for (let student of this.students) {
            console.log(`Name: ${student.name} Email: ${student.email}`);
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```